# best practice in launching python executable for webapps in test/production servers

Tags: python, web-applications, cherrypy

I've only ever done little small-scale apps for fun, but I feel like I'm starting up python webapps wrongly on any server I have (i.e. not locally for testing). I always seem to end up typing out "python app.py ..." either directly or into a shell script, and then running it - then finding a hacky way to monitor and bring it up when it's down. Luckily I tend to use CherryPy so once its up I can ssh in and update my code and it'll restart nicely - though I guess this is sort of hacky anyway.

Now the deployment of the code or the monitoring itself is not what I am interested in at the moment (though I agree its important) it's how people usually launch their sites.

Heroku had a nice way, where you'd run a command like "heroku push " and that would deploy your code to your heroku instance start it up - but presumably something on their end is invoking the python/pypy interpreter at some point.

So what do you do? Is there a generally accepted best practice at all, or does everyone tend to roll their own hacked together shell scripts or someting?

Answer (score 1):

[Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)  is a popular choice among many.